# Using awk command in perl script

Tags: scripts, perl, awk

Can somebody suggest how to use piping of commands in a perl script?
Specifically commands that involve calling `awk`?

I'm trying to create a perl script that will read disk usage using `df -H` and return the second-last row of output, which shows the %use.
Entering the command directly in the terminal returns the desired output.

```
df -H | awk '{print $(NF-3)}'
```

This command is returning the right results. But when using the same command in the reverse tick utility, the perl script throws a lot of errors.

```
$thirdlast=`df -H | awk '{print $(NF-3)}'`;
print $thirdlast;
```

Why does the same command not run in the script? Is there any other way to return the required results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem is that the `$` is important to perl. When you use it in a system command, you need to escape it:

```
$thirdlast=`df -H | awk '{print \$(NF-3)}'`;
print $thirdlast;
```

Otherwise, perl will try to expand `$(NF-3)` as a perl variable. The variable `$(` [is the perl process's real GID](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> $(
>
> The real gid of this process. If you are on a machine that supports membership in multiple groups simultaneously, gives a space separated list of groups you are in.

The variable `$)` is the process's effective GID:

So, `$(NF-3)` evaluates to `list of groups you are a member of NF-3)`. For example, on my system, that is:

```
$ perl -le 'print "$(NF-3)"'
1001 27 29 111 112 1001NF-3)
```

The next problem is that your `awk` call is wrong. The `%` use is `$(NF-1)`, not `$(NF-3)`. So, what you wanted is:

```
$thirdlast=`df -H | awk '{print \$(NF-1)}'`;
```

Or, to only print percentages above a certain threshold, for example 90:

```
$thirdlast=`df -H | awk '(\$(NF-1)>90){print \$(NF-1)}'`;
```

In any case, you could just process the output of `df` in Perl itself:

```
$thirdlast=`df -H`;
@matches=($thirdlast=~/(\S+%)/g);
print "@matches\n";
```

Or

```
@matches=(`df -H`=~/(\S+%)/g);
print "@matches\n";
```

And to set a threshold:

```
@matches=(`df -H`=~/(\S+%)/g);
@above90=grep {$_>90} @matches;
print "@above90\n";
```

Or, more directly:

```
@matches=grep {$_ >90} (`df -H`=~/(\S+%)/g);
print "@matches\n";
```

The `@array=($variable=~/foo/g)` will save all matches of the regular expression `foo` in the variable `$variable` into the array `@matches`. That will have the same result as parsing the `df` with `awk`.

Comment: It Works..!  Also, how to fetch when some of the values in this output exceeds 90%....? can i use < grep -oh "\w*9\w*" > piped from previous output? This works in terminal, again, not in perl script.

Comment: @kiranbbnl see updated answer. Next time, please ask your entire question instead of asking for extra details in the comments. Also, please see [here](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) for what to do when someone answers your question.