# How to compare/fetch the greater value in perl script?

Tags: grep, perl

Trying a perl script to fetch the % of hard disk usage. [By fetching the 5th column of the 'df -H' output, shows percentage of use].

```
$thirdlast=`df -H`;
@matches=($thirdlast=~/(\S+%)/g);
print "@matches\n";
```

Its giving the output.

```
Use% 3% 1% 1% 0% 1%
```

Now it is needed to fetch the value if any of these out put goes above 90%.
Tried grepping like this.['3' here, '9' in actual script, for 90% to 99% values]

```
perl script.pl | grep -oh "3\w*"
3
```

But the problems are:

1. This works in terminal but not in script.
2. If we grep "9*", value '9' also will be considered right?

What could be done? Any other option other than 'grep'..?

Answer (score 1):

You can use numeric comparison in Perl:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -l
@lines = `df -H`;
for (@lines) {
    @cols = split;
    print $cols[4] if $cols[4] > $ARGV[0];
}
```

Run as

```
script.pl 90
```

Comment: This is a shell script, not a perl script. The perl script is contained in single quotes.

Comment: @kiranbbnl: Check the update.

Comment: It works, but still, the next step is to make the perl script send a mail once it gets an output to the process. [which means hdd 90% above] . But the threshold value is in command right? How to add a cron job for this? It requires a full perl script which can fetch the value if it is greater than 90 and sends a mail. That is the end of the process. How can this be done sir?

Comment: @kiranbbnl: If you want to create cron jobs, you should read `man cron`. To send email, use [Email::Sender](http://p3rl.org/Email::Sender) or similar.

Comment: Sir, Creating cron job is ok. But is it possible to create a script in which the threshold value '90' is in the script itself? and the output which can be piped to the remaining process of sending mail? I dont have any clue, how to add this output to sending mail, since the threshold is in the command.

Comment: End of the day, what i want is, if the above script returns a value, (means the usage is above 90%), the perl script itself should send a mail, else exit. And then i can add that script to cron job to repeat every 30 minutes. Please help with the script sir.

Comment: @kiranbbnl as I told you [before](http://askubuntu.com/questions/623198/using-awk-command-in-perl-script/623208#comment883356_623208), you need to ask your _entire_ question. Don't ask small parts of it and then try and get the rest from comments. Edit your question and clarify what your needs are.

Comment: or better, create a new question "How do I send an email from a Perl script?".

Comment: Ok .. got it.. this would do better and useful: Please update sir: http://askubuntu.com/questions/623552/how-to-create-a-perl-script-which-checks-the-system-statscpu-ram-hdd-and-sends

Comment: @kiranbbnl not a question saying "This is what I want to do, please do it for me". We meant a question, like the ones you've asked, that i) shows the work you've done and ii) clearly explains, unlike the ones you've asked, precisely what you need. You still need to put some effort into writing all the bits you can and only ask for help on the rest.

Comment: Clear..! Thanks for the patience and please see the updated question.