# How to create a perl script which checks the system stats(CPU,RAM,HDD) and sends an alert mail?

Tags: scripts, cron, mail, perl

The script is for adding to the cron tab.
The flow of the shell script should be like this.
1. Checks the CPU state.
2. Checks the RAM usage.
3. Checks the HDD usage.
4.Sends an alert mail to recipients if any of these are above the threshold value. (say 90%)

> @matches=grep {$_ >90} (`df -H`=~/(\S+%)/g);
>
> print "@matches\n";

This returns the output of 'df _H' if it is above 90%

for RAM,

> free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'

The above command returns the RAM usage in percentage

Now, this should be compared with a threshold of 80%.
Then, if any of the above values [HDD/RAM] is on high side, the program should send a mail appending with the result of 'top' command in it, to show the cpu usage.

Please help.

This is to be added to the cron tab to run in equal intervals. 
Kindly update.

Comment: @heemayl : Kindly check update.

Comment: You are still laying your expectations in our laps and say: "Please write a complete script for me" - voting to close as "too broad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start.

Create `load.sh` script

`nano /path/load.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

#we use output from "uptime" i "w" to have load on 5 min

UPTIME=`uptime`;
W=`w`;
RAM=`free -m`;
DATE=`date`;
sleep 3
DF=`df -h`
sleep 3

echo "######################################" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "$DATE" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "UPTIME:" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "$UPTIME" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "W COMMAND:" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "$W" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "FREE RAM:" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "$RAM" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "FREE SPACE:" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "$DF" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
echo "#####################################" >> /var/log/load-result/load_log
```

give script X permision

```
chmod 777 /path/load.sh
```

Create dir for storing a log file

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/load-result
```

Create script to send mails

`nano /path/mail.sh`

```
mail -s Load_From_PC soma@email.com < /var/log/load-result/load_log
```

Give X `mail.sh`

```
chmod 777 /path/mail.sh
```

Create cron jobs

`sudo crontab -e`

```
*/5 * * * * /path/load.sh
00 11 * * * /path/mail.sh
```

`load.sh` will executed on every 5 min and result from script will be added on bottom in log file.

`mail.sh` will be triggered every day at 11:00 h

You can change time ...

Comment: Great..! But still, as in the question, how does the script compare with threshold values and sends an alert mail? This script simply appends the values in the file right? I would appreciate perl scripts if possible.